# Image URL does not insert image in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I am using tinymce , it works great. Now, I want to insert the image (For example:-http://danny.oz.au/travel/mongolia/p/56255254-flower.jpg) in text area attached with Tinymce editor.For this i clicked the insert image icon, small pop-up opens and i pasted my above flower url in Image URL  textbox. But it does not insert the image neither in preview part nor in tinymce text area. I am using the same demo code  given at [url]http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php.[/url] There this links works fine(also shows image in preview and parent tinymce editor ) . I am not sure what i am missing here? Do i need some extra file to make image url work?

Comment: looks like you missed something, if you think there is any other reason for it, reinstall tinymce may help!